# JavaScript Limit Drop Down Menu To Number In Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, onchange

I'm trying to get the drop down menu limited to whatever number you put in the max mark input field. E.G. if you put 10 in the max marks input field the drop down menu in the marks field is limited to 10

I tried using onchange but couldn't figure out how to use the number I put in the max mark field in the for loop I have made to create the drop down menu

```js
$(document).ready(function ()  {
    load();
});

function load(){
    $("#txtNoOfRec").focus();

    $("#btnNoOfRec").click(function () {
        $("#AddControll").empty();
        var NoOfRec = $("#txtNoOfRec").val();

        if(NoOfRec > 0) {
            createControll(NoOfRec);
        }
    });
}



function createControll(NoOfRec) {
    var tbl = "";

    tbl = "<table>"+
               "<tr>"+
                   "<th> Section </th>"+
                   "<th> Max </th>"+
                   "<th> Comment </th>"+
                   "<th> Marks </th>"+
               "</tr>";

    for (i=1; i<=NoOfRec; i++) {
        tbl += "<tr>"+
                        "<td>"+
                            "<input type='text' id='txtSection' placeholder='Section' autofocus/>"+
                        "</td>"+
                        "<td>"+
                            "<input type='text' id='txtMax' placeholder='Max' />"+
                        "</td>"+
                         "<td>"+
                            "<input type='text' id='txtComment' placeholder='Comment' />"+
                        "</td>"+
                        "<td>"+
                            "<select id='ddlMarks'>";
        for (let a = 0; a <= 100; a++) {
          tbl += "<option>" + a + "</option>";

        }
        tbl += "</select>"+
                        "</td>"+
                    "</tr>";
    }
    tbl += "</table>";

    $("#AddControll").append(tbl);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="dvMain">
    <label id="lblNoOfRec"> Enter No Of Rows</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtNoOfRec"/>
    <input type="button" value="CREATE" id="btnNoOfRec" />
</div>
<br>
<div id="AddControll">
</div>
```

Comment: you want `ddlMarks` to have the same amount of `<option>` as your input right? Just loop thru using `NoOfRec` as your condition like you did above. The Marks column, is that where you want the same amount of items as the input? the rows are already created correctly

Comment: I want the drop down menu to be the same as what you input in the form in the max marks input field not what you put in the input field that creates the number of rows

Comment: See updated answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to loop thru `NoOfRec` the same way you are making the table rows

Instead of looping thru 100 `for (let a = 0; a <= 100; a++) {` you just loop thru the input number `for (var a = 1; a <= NoOfRec; a++) {`.

**Updated answer**

Due to comments from OP, I have updated the code to determine the dropdown options based on the input from the `max` field generated from the table

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  load();
});

function load() {
  $("#txtNoOfRec").focus();

  $("#btnNoOfRec").click(function() {
    $("#AddControll").empty();
    var NoOfRec = $("#txtNoOfRec").val();

    if (NoOfRec > 0) {
      createControll(NoOfRec);
    }
  });
  
  $("#AddControll").on( "keyup", ".txtMax", function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    
    // get the input value
    var l = parseInt( $this.val() );
    
    // if input is a number then append items in dropdown
    if( typeof l == 'number' ) {
      // find the row parent tr and get the dropdown element then empty it first
      var $marks = $this.closest('tr').find('.ddlMarks');
      $marks.empty();
      
      // add dropdown items based on input
      for (var j = 0; j < l; j++) {
        $marks.append("<option>" + j + "</option>");
      }
    }
  } );
}

function createControll(NoOfRec) {
  var tbl = "";

  tbl = "<table>" +
    "<tr>" +
    "<th> Section </th>" +
    "<th> Max </th>" +
    "<th> Comment </th>" +
    "<th> Marks </th>" +
    "</tr>";

  for (i = 1; i <= NoOfRec; i++) {
    // ID must be unique, updated ID on inputs/select to use class instead
    tbl += "<tr>" +
      "<td>" +
      "<input type='text' class='txtSection' placeholder='Section' autofocus/>" +
      "</td>" +
      "<td>" +
      "<input type='text' class='txtMax' placeholder='Max' />" +
      "</td>" +
      "<td>" +
      "<input type='text' class='txtComment' placeholder='Comment' />" +
      "</td>" +
      "<td>" +
      "<select class='ddlMarks'>";
    for (var a = 0; a < 100; a++) {
      tbl += "<option>" + a + "</option>";
    }

    tbl += "</select>" +
      "</td>" +
      "</tr>";
  }
  tbl += "</table>";

  $("#AddControll").append(tbl);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="dvMain">
  <label id="lblNoOfRec"> Enter No Of Rows</label>
  <input type="text" id="txtNoOfRec" />
  <input type="button" value="CREATE" id="btnNoOfRec" />
</div>
<br>
<div id="AddControll">
</div>
```

Comment: I want the drop down menu to be the same as what you input in the form in the max marks input field not what you put in the input field that creates the number of rows

Comment: @user123456789 there are a few fields in the table, section, max, comments and marks(dropdown). Please specify which one is the "max mark" field you are referring to

Comment: I want the the marks drop down menu to go from 0 to whatever number you put  in the max field